# Updating Query Object in List Box using a Form. (MS-Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Objective is to make a form that has queried all the objects of a table that are defined as 'active'. That query is displayed as a list box on the form. I would like the user who accesses this form to be able to select an object of that query, and then update the table by selecting the action from a second list box, and then clicking the submit button.

Visually:
[image]

The on click VBA I assume will look something like this:

```
Private Sub ActionAdminbtn_Click()
Set Actiontbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Actiontbl]")
Actiontbl.Edit
Actiontbl![Progress] = Me.AdminActionSelect
Actiontbl.Update
Actiontbl.Close
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

This almost works for me, however I'm missing the line of code that selects the object from the list box. Right now, once clicking the action and submitting, I only change the first record in the table. Not the desired one. Any Suggestions on how to modify the selected object?

*Edit below to include more:*
Here's my table I'm trying to edit.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first listbox is bound to the unique key, ID, of your screenshot (hidden on form), consider an update SQL query with `WHERE` clause. Below demonstrates a parameterized query called using [QueryDef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845129.aspx) object.

**SQL** *(save as a stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [ProgressParam] TEXT(255), [ActionIDParam] Long;
UPDATE [Actiontbl] SET [Progress] = [ProgressParam]
WHERE ID = [ActionIDParam]
```

**VBA**

```
Private Sub ActionAdminbtn_Click()
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myUpdateQuery")
    ' BIND PARAMS
    qdef![ProgressParam] = Me.AdminActionSelect
    qdef![ActionIDParam] = Me.FirstListBoxName

    ' EXECUTE ACTION
    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

    Set qdef = Nothing

    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to stay with your Recordset `Update` approach, open the query conditioned to *ActionID* item, still assuming listbox's value is bound to hidden ID field.

```
Private Sub ActionAdminbtn_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim Actiontbl As Recordset

   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Actiontbl] WHERE ID=" & Me.FirstListBoxName

   Set Actiontbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

   Actiontbl.Edit
   Actiontbl![Progress] = Me.AdminActionSelect
   Actiontbl.Update
   Actiontbl.Close

   Set Actiontbl = Nothing

   Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering this. It was a perfect solution to my problem!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your ListBox control is named, but assuming `ListBox` is the name:

```
Dim iSel As Integer

iSel = ListBox.Value
```

This will give you the selected row for the list box. Then you could probably use either a recordset update method or a simplier `RowSource` update.

For any specific suggestions, we would need to see example data and column names of the table in question.

*NOTE: These types of updates are much easier using an ID key field.*