# Edit a field in record(s) selected from a listbox with a value from a combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a way to keep track of the workflow of some paper forms in my office. So far, I have a form with a listbox that will display all incomplete paperwork. In order to keep track of where the physical paperwork moved, I would like to highlight the record(s) in the list and assign them to an employee -- editing the field "QCByName" in tblForms from its current value (most often blank) to the value selected in a combobox that's pulling the options from tblStaff.

Form with listbox and combobox selection:

[image]

I'm having trouble with the VBA code for the command button, though. I have a decent working example from an older database someone else designed but haven't been successful in adapting the code to my similar situation. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198296/updating-query-object-in-list-box-using-a-form-ms-access) seemed helpful, but I can't get it to work.

If I try to assign one row in the list box to someone, I get a run-time error:

> 3075: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ID=15T362'

Where 15T362 is the FormNumber row I selected. The listbox is unbound, I think, but the primary key and first (hidden) field is the ID.

Here's the current code. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
Private Sub cmdAssigntoQC_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim tblForms As Recordset

If IsNull(Combo5) Then
    MsgBox "No Changes Made"

Else
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [tblForms] WHERE ID=" & List0
    Set tblForms = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    tblForms.Edit
    tblForms![QCByName] = Me.Combo5
    tblForms.Update
    tblForms.Close

Set tblForms = Nothing

Forms!frmOutstanding.L0Req
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe the ID value needs surrounding with single quotes?  `ID=" & List0` => `ID='" & List0 & "'"` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Progress, at least. Now it's a run-time error 3464: data type mismatch in criteria expression. Any ideas? I'll do some searching and examine the existing code for mismatches.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used Access, but what is the data type of the `ID` column?  I assumed a string, but it might be a number at the table level. That or maybe instead of `ID`, the column should be `FormNumber` instead?

Comment: If ID is a number type, listbox value must be a number yet you show a string. Should be pulling value from hidden ID column if BoundColumn is set to 1.

Comment: Ah, good call! Yes, the ID is numeric. I changed ```Dim strSQL As String``` to ```Dim strSQL As Long``` but now get run-time error 13: type mismatch. I could also change the column to ```FormNumber``` since it is a unique value. Might be easier to make that the primary key for that table, too. Tried it briefly, but it's late and I might not be thinking it through well. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: The `strSQL` should be a string for the query, changing to long would be the wrong direction to go. What @June7 said about the `BoundColumn` value is likely the value to use instead of the `FormNumber`. That way, you can keep the `ID` column as-is, but use the hidden ID column's value instead, and you would not need the single quotes added previously.

Comment: Ok, I might not be understanding this correctly. Keeping ```BoundColumn``` at 1 for the hidden numeric ```ID``` column, changing ```strSQL``` back to a string, and removing the single quotes (back to ```ID=" & List0```) lands me right back where I started with the same error. Apologies for the confusion -- it's been a long time since I've used Access.

Comment: I just did some experimenting with listbox and it is not working. I haven't used listbox much so had to refresh memory. I must have been basing my suggestion on use of combobox. Handling listbox is a bit different from combobox. Have to use Column property and reference column by its index: `Me.List0.Column(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull value from selected listbox item, have to use Column property and reference column by its index, index begins with 0: `Me.List0.Column(0)`

Using `Me.` qualifier is not required but it will trigger intellisense tips.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. I had to adjust a few things. When building the listbox, I swear I included the ID column as hidden, but reviewing the query builder the ID column doesn't appear there. so ```Column(0)``` is actually ```FormNumber```. I left ```strSQL``` as a string and updated strSQL to ```FormNumber='" & Me.List0.Column(0) & "'"```. That will work just fine since ```FormNumber``` is a unique value corresponding to only one record. Thanks for the help @June7 and @Paul-t . Now onto figuring out how to apply changes to 2+ selections with multiselect listbox!